# Is Moffat leaving Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, production

I've heard it as a rumour from a few friends, but can this really be happening? Is there a trustworthy source that validates this claim? Also, why is he leaving, and who is to replace him? I'm rather concerned for the well-being of one of my favorite TV shows.

Comment: Head writers have left Doctor Who before, and will leave it in the future.

Comment: All my favorite episodes actually pre-date the period where Moffat was show runner. I feel like he's better as a one-off writer but not so much as the show runner.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite They never leave; they just regenerate into a new body.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yeah I didn’t think Matt Smith got an individual episode that I could point to and go yes, that was a triumph. Day of the Doctor was great but it was multi-Doctor.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ahem: The Doctor's Wife! Though, to be fair, they did bring in an *accomplished* writer for that one.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ahem: Pandorica/BigBang2 ?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, he's definitely a great deal better when someone else is holding the reins. IMO he basically needs an editor to go "yeah it's a fun idea, but it doesn't actually WORK" (c.f. Statue Of Liberty is a WA, and Angels chasing down opposite ends of a corridor)

Comment: @Brondahl: well, that’s a two-parter, and perhaps a little over-complicated, plot-wise (relying, as it does, on a bootstrap paradox without so much as a nice little chalkboard explanation), and is part of a bunch of threads that are resolved without much impact.

Comment: @Politank-Z: good shout, I’d go for that. (And to be clear, I think Steven Moffat is an incredibly accomplished writer who’s done tremendous work on Doctor Who as writer and showrunner.)

Comment: This was the best news I heard! :P Moffat is a good writer but a terrible show runner. When he's gone I might start watching it again.

Comment: @curiousdannii Lots of people would agree that Series 9 was the best for a long time and redeemed Moffat somewhat. You might want to consider giving it a try if you've given up DW because of Moffat :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I watched the first two episodes of season 9, but they were just so ridiculous and dumb (and not in a way that entertained me, though I'm sure they entertained others.) I tried watching another episode that had Maisie Williams in it, but it didn't keep me interested enough to finish the episode :/

Comment: rumour? This was news weeks ago and google would have produced the answer much more quickly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Yes, Moffat is leaving Doctor Who at the end of 2017.

From [this article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-35388748) officially released by the BBC itself:

> The head writer and executive producer of Doctor Who, Steven Moffat, is to step down from the show, the BBC has confirmed.
>
> His last series will go out in spring 2017 following a Christmas special, after which he will be replaced by Broadchurch writer [Chris Chibnall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Chibnall).
>
> [...]
>
> "At the start of season 11, Chris Chibnall will become the new showrunner of Doctor Who. And I will be thrown in a skip."

[This article](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/Steven-Moffat-Final-Doctor-Who-Episode-Air-142547.html) from Cinema Blend confirms that Moffat will stay for the 2017 Christmas special as well as the preceding Series 10:

> Steven Moffat has been the showrunner on Doctor Who since 2010, but the long-running series is about to go through a slew of changes. Not only is current lead Peter Capaldi getting a brand new companion in Pearl Mackie during Season 10, but Steven Moffat is also preparing to step down as the showrunner on the series. Now, we finally know when the changeover is going to take place, but it looks as if it won’t happen for a while, yet. Steven Moffat just [confirmed](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/How-Close-Doctor-Who-Came-Having-Black-Time-Lord-According-Steven-Moffat-142457.html) he will not be stepping down as soon as Season 10 ends. Instead, he will stick around for the Christmas special in 2017, as well.

Comment: Fastest Gun in the West much? o_o

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ 15 seconds!

Comment: The worst thing about this news is that it confirms we don’t get a series of Doctor Who this year :(

Comment: Well, at least we get a Christmas special (*dodges chair thrown at him*)

Comment: @tilley31 if we *didn’t* get a Christmas Doctor Who I’d lead a violent overthrow of the government, or at least write a *very* strongly-worded letter to the BBC.

Comment: Does this mean we get the right music and intro back?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Why not a violent overthrow of the BBC network executive system?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Isn't that the modern British equivalent of a violent overthrow? /sarcasm